# Is it possible to trigger location change without battery drain?

Tags: android, location, battery, android-gps

In my application I need to get an update for the user's location when entering another city.

So for example:

1. User lives in cityA
2. User travels from cityA to cityB
3. A function should be triggered.

I see just the following functions are provided by Google play services:

1. `public abstract Location getLastLocation (GoogleApiClient client)`
2. `public abstract PendingResult<Status> requestLocationUpdates (GoogleApiClient client, LocationRequest request, LocationListener listener)`

The problem is:

**I need to track the user's city location changes continuously, not just when the user is using the app.**

How could I do that without draining the battery too fast?

Comment: What about onLocationChanged method?
You can use it in some kind of service. And you can receive events even your app is closed

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use broadcast receivers for this. There is a documentation at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html.

`private static final LocationRequest REQUEST = LocationRequest.create()
        .setFastestInterval(60000)   // in milliseconds
        .setInterval(180000)         // in milliseconds
        .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_LOW_POWER);`

```
'@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
        mGoogleApiClient,
        REQUEST,
        this);  // LocationListener
}`
```

Use FusedLocationApi and you will be good to go.